# Compare two strings one shifted by a position

Tags: java, string, string-matching

I have theses two strings:

```
String s1 = "hello"; 
String s2 ="_hello";
```

I wish to return `true` (the second string is shifted by a position) for such strings when I compare them.

Which `String` manipulation method should I use? Can anyone give me a hint on this?

Comment: This both string is any result?

Comment: Why not just `s2.equals('_' + s1)` ?

Comment: Don't use any punctuation before the question mark.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `contains()` of String class.

```
String s1 = "hello";
String s2 ="_hello";

if(s2.contains(s1))
   //true
```

You can also use `subString()`

```
s2= s2.subString(1);
if(s2.equalsIgnoreCase(s1))
   //true
```

And yes you can also use `indexOf()`

```
if(s2.indexOf(s1)>-1)
   //true
```

Comment: Might also look at building a test around indexOf() if the fact that it is offset is of importance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use indexOf method:

```
int index=s2.indexOf(s1);

if(index ==-1) // s1 is not present into s2.
```

else index is the index of first character into s2 matching s1. for example in case:

```
String s1 = "hello"; String s2 ="_hello";
```

index will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't programmed for android, so take this with a grain of salt, but take a look at String.indexOf(). I believe Android is based on Java, so that should help.